# Why is one level of my data missing in my multivariate regression in rstudio?

Tags: r

I am (again) having a problem with Rstudio. I'm running a mutivariate regression. One of my predictor variables has multiple levels. For some reason the first level is missing.

````
```{r}
levels(ESS$hinctnta_REC)
```
 [1] "J - 1st decile"  "R - 2nd decile"  "C - 3rd decile"  "M - 4th decile" 
 [5] "F - 5th decile"  "S - 6th decile"  "K - 7th decile"  "P - 8th decile" 
 [9] "D - 9th decile"  "H - 10th decile" "Refusal"         "Don't know"     
 [13] "No answer" 

```{r}
model1 <- lm(ESS$freehomosexuals_NUM2 ~ ESS$worseorbetterplacetolive_NUM2 + ESS$rlgblg_REC + 
ESS$hinctnta_REC, data = ESS)
summary(model1)
```
Call:
lm(formula = ESS$freehomosexuals_NUM2 ~ ESS$worseorbetterplacetolive_NUM2 + 
ESS$rlgblg_REC + ESS$hinctnta_REC, data = ESS)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.14129 -0.63621  0.08439  0.36379  1.72209 

Coefficients:
                                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                        1.441386   0.018085  79.699  < 2e-16 ***
ESS$worseorbetterplacetolive_NUM2  0.157964   0.006512  24.257  < 2e-16 ***
ESS$rlgblg_REC1                    0.226011   0.007391  30.581  < 2e-16 ***
ESS$hinctnta_RECR - 2nd decile    -0.028366   0.015909  -1.783   0.0746 .  
ESS$hinctnta_RECC - 3rd decile    -0.067715   0.015791  -4.288 1.81e-05 ***
ESS$hinctnta_RECM - 4th decile    -0.096692   0.015927  -6.071 1.29e-09 ***
ESS$hinctnta_RECF - 5th decile    -0.121103   0.015914  -7.610 2.81e-14 ***
ESS$hinctnta_RECS - 6th decile    -0.122475   0.016052  -7.630 2.41e-14 ***
ESS$hinctnta_RECK - 7th decile    -0.162637   0.015959 -10.191  < 2e-16 ***
ESS$hinctnta_RECP - 8th decile    -0.219497   0.016169 -13.575  < 2e-16 ***
ESS$hinctnta_RECD - 9th decile    -0.296647   0.017601 -16.854  < 2e-16 ***
ESS$hinctnta_RECH - 10th decile   -0.321444   0.017920 -17.938  < 2e-16 ***
 ---
 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.6707 on 34229 degrees of freedom
  (10146 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.06503,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.06473 
F-statistic: 216.4 on 11 and 34229 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
````

Comment: Because that's how multiple regression works.

Comment: But why just this one :"J - 1st decile"? Sorry I'm absolutely clueless. It's the first time I'm doing this.

Comment: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/spss/faq/coding-systems-for-categorical-variables-in-regression-analysis/